# Understanding heartbeat in ASP.NET health monitoring

Tags: asp.net, diagnostics, health-monitoring

Who's triggering the event? What are consequences/benefits of enabling it in `<healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="30">` except it appears every 30 seconds in the logs? Has it anything to do with NLB heartbeat?  What interval is better for production use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling it in this way in the web.config will cause the Application Domain to raise a `WebHeartbeatEvent` periodically (in your case every 30 seconds), basically to check if your application is 'still alive' (like checking a human's heartbeat). You can specify additional rules like this:

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="100">
  <rules>
    <add name="Heart Beat Events"
      eventName="Heartbeats"
      provider="EventLogProvider"
      profile="Default"
      minInterval="00:01:00" />
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

Specifying '`EventLogProvider`' will cause the events to be logged to the EventLog, but you could also write your own Provider, [see here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227676.aspx)

It has nothing to do with the NLB heartbeat by the way, which is only used for Load Balancing purposes.

Comment: Does that mean my app pool will never be recycled if recycle period is greater than heartbeatInterval?

Comment: @UserControl: What makes you think so?

Comment: I don't then understand "to check if your application is 'still alive'". So who's raising the event? ASP.NET worker process? Or is it raised by the application itself? If latter and the app is idle IIS will recycle it, won't it?

Comment: @UserControl: The events are raised by the application domain. So yes, I assume the application pool will be recycled by IIS. HeartbeatInterval is not a way to keep your app alive, only to monitor it.